# Diagonalization of Linear Mapping Associated to a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization

Assume T to be the linear operator on $R^4$ whose matrix relative to the standard basis is

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & c & 0  \end{bmatrix}$$

When would T be diagonalisable?

I know that Q is not diagonalisable because the diagonal is all 0's and I thought the associated matrix is diagonalisable if and only if linear operator is diagonalisable.

Comment: Depends on what $a,b,c$ are. Note that $Q$ is diagonalizable if and only if $E_0 = \ker(Q-0I)=\ker Q$ has dimension $4$; i.e if and only if $Q=0$.

Comment: T got to have at least 4 eigenvalues if im right but there is only 3 linearly independent columns so how would a,b,c values make T diagnolisable?

Comment: I updated my comment to give the necessary and sufficient conditions; it is diagonalizable if and only if $a=b=c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $x^4$, so, $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$. Now note that $v \in \mathbb R^4 \setminus \{0\}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ if and only if $v \in \ker T$. Thus, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if there are four linearly independent vectors in $\ker T$, that is, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\ker T = \mathbb R^4$, which means, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $T=0$ $(a=b=c=0)$.

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense; I was just diagnolizing and doing rref on Q to find out that Q has to be a zero matrix; i was wondering if Q is diagnolizable i.f.f T is diagnolizable is true, just by definition?

Comment: Yes, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $Q$ is diagonalizable. Also, note that the rref of $Q$ **is** the zero matrix only if $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: thanks, just to double check 1) "now note that v is an eigenvector i.f.f..." is because $ker(T-0I)=kerT$ right? 2) Why is T diagnolizable i.f.f. there are four linearly independent vectors?

Comment: 1) Right. 2) That's because $T$ is diagonalizable if there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Comment: sorry do you mean linearly independent eigenvectors which is linearly independent vectors you mentioned in the answer? if so why is this--is this a complete seperate proof?

Comment: Don't worry. Yes, I said "linearly independent vectors *in* $\ker T$" instead of "linearly independent eigenvectors" because all the eigenvectors of $T$ are in $\ker T$.